# OPcacheをインストールする時に出るエラーについて

Tags: php, linux, yum

OPcacheを導入したいのですが、インストールでエラーが発生して先に進みません。
`yum -y install --enablerepo=epel,remi,remi-php71 php-opcache php-pecl-apcu`
上記実行すると下記のエラーが出ます。何をしたらよいのでしょうか？

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main                                                                                                   | 2.1 kB  00:00:00
amzn-updates                                                                                                | 2.5 kB  00:00:00
1416 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-opcache.x86_64 0:7.1.28-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 7.1.28-1.el6.remi for package: php-opcache-7.1.28-1.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-pecl-apcu.x86_64 0:5.1.17-1.el6.remi.7.1 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-opcache-7.1.28-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php71)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 7.1.28-1.el6.remi
           Available: php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-main)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.29-1.8.amzn1
           Available: php54-common-5.4.45-1.75.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-main)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.45-1.75.amzn1
           Available: php55-common-5.5.38-2.119.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-main)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.38-2.119.amzn1
           Available: php56-common-5.6.35-1.137.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-main)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.35-1.137.amzn1
           Available: php56-common-5.6.36-1.138.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.36-1.138.amzn1
           Available: php56-common-5.6.37-1.139.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.37-1.139.amzn1
           Available: php56-common-5.6.38-1.140.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.38-1.140.amzn1
           Available: php56-common-5.6.39-1.141.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.39-1.141.amzn1
           Available: php56-common-5.6.40-1.142.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.40-1.142.amzn1
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

追記です
OS:Amazon Linux AMI release 2017.09
PHP:PHP 7.1.25

```
# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
92 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
repo id                                  repo name                                                                         status
!amzn-main/latest                        amzn-main-Base                                                                       5,934
!amzn-updates/latest                     amzn-updates-Base                                                                    2,097
remi-php71                               Remi's PHP 7.1 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64                       307+76
remi-safe                                Safe Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64                        2,793+16
repolist: 11,131
```

Comment: 念のため、利用している「OSの種類」「phpのバージョン」、および`yum repolist`の実行結果を質問文に追記してみてください (質問は後からでも [編集] できます)。

Comment: 追記しました。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。
Amazon Linuxなので、remiではなく、amzn-updatesとamzn-mainを使った方がよいみたいです。
下記でインストールできました。

```
sudo yum install php71-opcache
sudo yum install php71-pecl-apcu
```

Answer (score 0):

`php-opcache`の依存パッケージ`php-common`が必要なので自動でインストールしようとしたけれど、

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 7.1.28-1.el6.remi for package: php-opcache-7.1.28-1.el6.remi.x86_64
```

複数バージョンが候補に出てきて解決できない状態です。

```
Error: Package: php-opcache-7.1.28-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php71)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 7.1.28-1.el6.remi
           Available: php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-main)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.29-1.8.amzn1
           Available: php54-common-5.4.45-1.75.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-main)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.45-1.75.amzn1
           Available: php55-common-5.5.38-2.119.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-main)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.38-2.119.amzn1
           Available: php56-common-5.6.35-1.137.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-main)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.35-1.137.amzn1
           Available: php56-common-5.6.36-1.138.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.36-1.138.amzn1
           Available: php56-common-5.6.37-1.139.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.37-1.139.amzn1
           Available: php56-common-5.6.38-1.140.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.38-1.140.amzn1
           Available: php56-common-5.6.39-1.141.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.39-1.141.amzn1
           Available: php56-common-5.6.40-1.142.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.40-1.142.amzn1
```

恐らく必要なのはremiリポジトリのパッケージなので、デフォルトで有効になっているamzn-main, amzn-updatesを`--disablerepo`オプションで無効にした状態でyumを実行してみてください。

```
yum -y install --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=epel,remi,remi-php71 php-opcache php-pecl-apcu
```

`--disablerepo=\*`で「すべてのリポジトリを無効」にしたうえで、`--enablerepo=...`で必要なリポジトリのみ有効にします。

Comment: --disablerepo=\*で実行しました。
しかし、transaction checkでエラーになってしまいました。

Transaction check error:
  file /etc/php.d/20-bz2.ini from install of php-common-7.1.28-1.el6.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php71-common-7.1.25-1.35.amzn1.x86_64
  file /etc/php-zts.d/20-bz2.ini from install of php-common-7.1.28-1.el6.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php71-common-7.1.25-1.35.amzn1.x86_64
  file /etc/php.d/20-calendar.ini from install of php-common-7.1.28-1.el6.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php71-common-7.1.25-1.35.amzn1.x86_64
・
・
・
多かったので割愛

Answer (score 0):

`priorities` プラグインが有効で、amzn-main, amzn-updates が優先されているのだと思います。
yum に `--noplugins` オプションを付けてみてください。